# sbt - independent build definitions

Tags: scala, sbt

*Introduction to problem*:

I have a project that uses *Akka* and *Spray* that logically consists of two parts `A` and `B`. In the final version both of them will work together, exchange messages etc. At the moment I have implemented some functionality of part `B` and whole part `A`. If I run `sbt compile` not strangely I get errors that refer to part `B` only.

*Question*:

Is it possible to define some rule for `sbt` that will compile only modules that build part `A` exclusively ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cd /path/to/project
$ sbt
> projects
[info] In file:/path/to/project
[info]   * root
[info]     A
[info]     B
> project A
[info] Set current project to A (in build file:/path/to/project/)
> projects
[info] In file:/path/to/project
[info]     root
[info]   * A
[info]     B
> compile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a task for a certain project, you could use following syntax `<project>/compile`. In your example let's say `A/compile` or `B/compile`.

Alternatively you can automate the whole process by creating your own task.

#### `build.sbt`

```
val projectA, projectB = project

val compileA = taskKey[Unit]("Compiles project A")

val partA = ScopeFilter( inProjects(projectA), inConfigurations(Compile) )

compileA := compile.all( partA ).value
```

Now running `compileA` will compile all the projects mentioned in the `inProjects(...)` filter (you could have multiple).